# Unable to extract data from FCM notification when app is in background/kill in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

1. Able to receive data from push notifications when application is in foreground.
2. But not on background/ kill.
3. Receiving and posting data to activity using bundle from notification when application is in foreground.
4. Receiving notification even application background/kill. But not able to extract data .

For push notifications using firebase cloud messaging service.

If it is possible Can you suggest me to get out of this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By using OnNewIntent() method of fcm messaging service  we can process/save  notification  data.